# Synchronizing two tables using a stored procedure, only updating and adding rows where values do not match

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

### **The scenario**

I've got two tables with identical structure.

```TSQL
TABLE [INFORMATION], [SYNC_INFORMATION]

    [ITEM] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
    [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](255) NULL
    [EXTRA] [nvarchar](255) NULL
    [UNIT] [nvarchar](2) NULL
    [COST] [float] NULL
    [STOCK] [nvarchar](1) NULL
    [CURRENCY] [nvarchar](255) NULL
    [LASTUPDATE] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    [IN] [nvarchar](4) NULL
    [CLIENT] [nvarchar](255) NULL
```

I'm trying to create a synchronize procedure that will be triggered by a scheduled event at a given time every day.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SynchronizeInformation]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Update all rows
    UPDATE TARGET_TABLE
    SET TARGET_TABLE.[DESCRIPTION] = SOURCE_TABLE.[DESCRIPTION],
        TARGET_TABLE.[EXTRA] = SOURCE_TABLE.[EXTRA],
        TARGET_TABLE.[UNIT] = SOURCE_TABLE.[UNIT],
        TARGET_TABLE.[COST] = SOURCE_TABLE.[COST],
        TARGET_TABLE.[STOCK] = SOURCE_TABLE.[STOCK],
        TARGET_TABLE.[CURRENCY] = SOURCE_TABLE.[CURRENCY],
        TARGET_TABLE.[LASTUPDATE] = SOURCE_TABLE.[LASTUPDATE],
        TARGET_TABLE.[IN] = SOURCE_TABLE.[IN],
        TARGET_TABLE.[CLIENT] = SOURCE_TABLE.[CLIENT]
    FROM SYNC_INFORMATION TARGET_TABLE 
        JOIN LSERVER.dbo.INFORMATION SOURCE_TABLE ON TARGET_TABLE.ITEMNO = SOURCE_TABLE.ITEMNO
    WHERE TARGET_TABLE.ITEMNO = SOURCE_TABLE.ITEMNO

    --Add new rows
    INSERT INTO SYNC_INFORMATION (ITEMNO, DESCRIPTION, EXTRA, UNIT, STANDARDCOST, STOCKTYPE, CURRENCY_ID, LASTSTANDARDUPDATE, IN_ID, CLIENTCODE)
    SELECT 
        src.ITEM, 
        src.DESCRIPTION,
        src.EXTRA,
        src.UNIT,
        src.COST,
        src.STOCKTYPE,
        src.CURRENCY_ID,
        src.LASTUPDATE,
        src.IN,
        src.CLIENT
    FROM LSERVER.dbo.INFORMATION src
        LEFT JOIN SYNC_INFORMATION targ ON src.ITEMNO = targ.ITEMNO
    WHERE
        targ.ITEMNO IS NULL
END
```

Currently, this procedure (including some others that are also executed at the same time) takes about 15 seconds to execute.
I'm planning on adding a "Synchronize" button in my work interface so that users can manually synchronize when, for instance, a new item is added and needs to be used the same day.

But in order for me to do that, I need to trim those 15 seconds as much as possible.

---

Instead of updating every single row, like in my procedure, is it possible to only update rows that have values that does not match?
This would greatly increase the execution speed, since it doesn't have to update all the 4000 rows when maybe only 20 actually needs it.

Can this be done in a better way, or optimized?
Does it need improvements, if yes, where?

How would you solve this?

Would also appreciate some time differences between the solutions so I can compare them.

### UPDATE

Using marc_s's `CHECKSUM` is really brilliant. The problem is that in some instances the information creates the same checksum. Here's an example, due to the classified content, I can only show you 2 columns, but I can say that all columns have identical information except these 2. To clarify: this screenshot is of all the rows that had duplicate `CHECKSUM`s. These are also the only rows with a hyphen in the `ITEM` column, I've looked.

[image]

The query was simply

```
SELECT *, CHECKSUM(*) FROM SYNC_INFORMATION
```

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using?? SQL Server **2008** has the new `MERGE` command exactly for this kind of scenario....

Comment: @Fosco Should probably have mentioned that one of the tables are located on another very busy server, where I only have read permission. I'm using that data to do some calculations in my interface, so to take the workload off, I transfer the data to another server and only synchronize when it's needed.

Comment: @marc_s Both servers are 2005. Currently, the clustered index is the same as the primary key, `ITEMNO`. There are no other indices so far.

Comment: I can't see `ITEMNO` in your table structure...... what kind of column is it? An `INT` ??

Comment: @marc_s Oh, sorry, I changed the names. I'll fix it. `ITEMNO` _is_ `ITEM`, and it's a `nvarchar`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7814/discussion-between-shadowscripter-and-marc-s)

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't ever use a `NVARCHAR(1) NULL` - this will use between 2 and 4 bytes of storage - even when NULL. For strings of less than 5-10 chars, use the fixed width equivalents - NCHAR(1) is much better and always uses just 2 bytes (fixed) - no matter what.

Comment: From your description it seems to me the `SYNC_INFORMATION` table is more of a backup/copy of the `INFORMATION` table as you are only updating in one direction, from `INFORMATION` to `SYNC_INFORMATION`. If that is the case have you tested the speed of just deleting the table and performing a `SELECT * INTO SYNC_INFORMATION ...` query?

Comment: @Tony I'm making a copy of the table and then I make my own relationships in my own tables with the copied data, keeping structural integrity. I'd also imagine that deleting and recreating the table and then inserting all the rows all over again every single time would be a much more heavy task in comparison.

Comment: @ShadowScripter - You say you imagine it would take longer, have you tried it? How many rows are there in your source table? An alternative might be to use the `MERGE` command, again you would need to test to see if it is any faster. It's a shame you cannot modify the source DB as you could add triggers to replicate the data as and when it changes.

Comment: @Tony I've got some custom data mixed in there that would be deleted and never seen again, which is why I only update and add. Besides, there aren't that many updates being made on a weekly basis, and what would be the point in destroying and recreating the entire table if only 20 of all 4000 rows needs updating? Marc already asked if I could use `MERGE`, but it's not available on SQL 2005. The administrator on the other server is incredibly strict when it comes to security. There's no way he'd allow me to go in there and mess with his precious tables... he's like Gollum in LotR ;)

Comment: @ShadowScripter - Sorry, I missed marc_s asking about `MERGE`. In which case you need to find out if the slowest part is copying the data over the network or the joins to work out what needs updating. Have you tried copying the whole table over to your server and seeing how long that takes? I realise this is a variation on the `DROP\CREATE` but you might find it faster to copy all the data to a new table then perform your merge on your server. Can you post the execution plan of your query? It might help find the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the table structure ever so slightly - you could add a computed `CHECKSUM` column to your two tables, and in the case the `ITEM` is identical, you could then check that checksum column to see if there are any differences at all in the columns of the table.

If you can do this - try something like this here:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[INFORMATION]
  ADD CheckSumColumn AS CHECKSUM([DESCRIPTION], [EXTRA], [UNIT],
                                 [COST], [STOCK], [CURRENCY],
                                 [LASTUPDATE], [IN], [CLIENT]) PERSISTED
```

Of course: only include those columns that should be considered when making sure whether a source and a target row are identical ! (this depends on your needs and requirements)

This persists a new column to your table, which is calculated as the checksum over the columns specified in the list of arguments to the `CHECKSUM` function.

This value is persisted, i.e. it could be indexed, too! :-O

Now, you could simplify your `UPDATE` to

```
 UPDATE TARGET_TABLE
 SET ......
 FROM SYNC_INFORMATION TARGET_TABLE 
 JOIN LSERVER.dbo.INFORMATION SOURCE_TABLE ON TARGET_TABLE.ITEMNO = SOURCE_TABLE.ITEMNO
 WHERE 
     TARGET_TABLE.ITEMNO = SOURCE_TABLE.ITEMNO
     AND TARGET_TABLE.CheckSumColumn <> SOURCE_TABLE.CheckSumColumn
```

Read more about the [`CHECKSUM` T-SQL function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)!

Comment: I wrote in one of the comments that I only have read permissions on one of the servers. So I can't add any columns :/  However, I must say that that is a brilliant solution. It's like a custom HASH index on all the columns combined per row! Is it possible to do `TARGET_TABLE.ChecksumColumn <> CHECKSUM(column1, column2, column3, column4...)`, and also not taking up too much computations? Because that would be such an excellent solution.

Comment: @ShadowScripter: well yes , if you cannot change the source table, you can have it compute the `CHECKSUM` in the `SELECT` statement. Not quite as efficient as having it persisted to the table - but still hopefully a fairly good indicator whether or not something has changed!

Comment: Didn't work,  well actually it almost worked, but there were 7 rows that calculated the same checksum. Those rows are almost identical, where one had a 4 in `ITEM` and a 6 in `DESCRIPTION`, and the other had a 6 in `ITEM` and a 4 in `DESCRIPTION`, which resulted in the same checksum.

Comment: @ShadowScripter did you apply a checksum to a subset of columns? I couldn't get `INT`s or `VARCHAR`s to produce the same `CHECKSUM()` value for all combinations of (`4`,`6`). Can you show the actual rows and `CHECKSUM()` calculation that caused this collision?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Some of the information is classified, but I'll show you as much as I'm allowed.

Comment: @ShadowScripter Come on, help us help you. Can you get this to happen with data that isn't classified? Shouldn't be hard to obfuscate the data in those other columns instead of us needing to invent your symptom.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's the thing, I can't recreate the problem with any other data. I've got no clue why it's returning the same `CHECKSUM`. There are no duplicate `CHECKSUMS` before I do the sync though. These are the only one's that are doing it, all the other 4000 rows are just fine.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Interestingly, these are the only rows that have a hyphen in the `ITEM` string.

Comment: @ShadowScripter from the screen shot it looks like all the rows have a hyphen in the `ITEM` string.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Oh. Well, the screen shot is of all the rows with duplicate `CHECKSUM`s. That's why I put it in Excel; easier to find duplicates with conditional formatting and then filter them out.

Comment: @marc_s I forgot to mark as answered. The issue was resolved after I recreated the table on my end. Couldn't recreate the issue though. Such an excellent solution. Thanks for all the help!